# How to Auto Deploy .NET Core Web API to Local IIS Using GitHub Actions?

Tags: .net, deployment, action

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project. I have hosted this project on my local IIS Windows server. I have also uploaded this project to Git Hub.
**Now I want to set up the auto-publish/deploy method in my project so that with each git push github can publish my project to the local IIS**
Note: I want that yml file commands.